# Angular 7 responsive dropdown menu

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, angular7

Im building a responsive custom topnav in Angular 7

```
<nav id="nav" class="sticky" #stickyMenu [class.fixed] = "fixed">
        <ul>
          <li><a routerLink='home' routerLinkActive='activado'>Home</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink='projects' routerLinkActive='activado'>Projects and stuff</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink='contact' routerLinkActive='activado'>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul [ngClass]="{'toggleMenuStyle': toggleMenu === true}">
             <i class="fa fa-bars icon" (click)="onToggleMenu()"></i>
          <li><a routerLink='home' routerLinkActive='activado'>Home</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink='projects' routerLinkActive='activado'>Projects and stuff</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink='contact' routerLinkActive='activado'>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

in menu.component.ts...

```
toggleMenu = false;

onToggleMenu(){
    if(this.toggleMenu === true){
       this.toggleMenu = false;
    }else{
      this.toggleMenu = true;
    }
    console.log('click');
  }
```

and my css...

```
nav i {
  display: none;
  color:white;
}
.toggleMenuStyle{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
   nav ul li{
     display: none
   }
   nav i{
     display: block;
   }
}
```

when I make click the class changes and the console logs the click but in the body nothings happen..
Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your class added to `<ul>` element does totally nothing, just take a look closer:

```
.toggleMenuStyle {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

**1.** `display: block`. Element `<ul>` already has the same default value, as described in [Default CSS Settings](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) block.

**2.** `margin-bottom: 5px`. It applies but does totally nothing in this case.

You can check this **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-t81kmv?file=src/app/app.component.css)** with more expressive styles (`background-color: red` in this example).